# Swift SpriteKit - Appodeal.showAd GameViewController method access from GameScene not working

Tags: swift, class, methods, sprite-kit, adsense

Im trying to get the Appodeal sdk to work on my game.

```
    func showInterstitial(){
   let inter = AppodealShowStyle.Interstitial
     Appodeal.showAd(inter, rootViewController: self)
 }
```

Is the method in my GameViewController I'm trying to call from GameScene. There are no problems when I call it from the GameViewController itself.

I get a really long message in my console:

2016-06-05 15:54:29.257 3[95692:2076512]  Presenting the interstitial threw exception: Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' text:'1' fontName:'Futura' position:{384, 974} with trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x04fc5494 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0731fe02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x04fc53bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   SpriteKit                           0x07176953 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 182
    4   SpriteKit                           0x0717687b -[SKNode addChild:] + 84
    5   3                                   0x00034a38 _TFC1_9GameScene13didMoveToViewfCSo6SKViewT_ + 7240
    6   3                                   0x00034c5d _TToFC1_9GameScene13didMoveToViewfCSo6SKViewT_ + 61
    7   SpriteKit                           0x071442c1 -[SKScene _didMoveToView:] + 217
    8   SpriteKit                           0x0716433d -[SKView presentScene:] + 592
    9   3                                   0x00031dd8 _TFC1_18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 824
    10  3                                   0x00031eb2 _TToFC1_18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    11  UIKit                               0x0268cb72 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 44
    12  UIKit                               0x02691692 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1384
    13  UIKit                               0x02691ab1 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    14  UIKit                               0x026a5c7c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3881
    15  UIKit                               0x026a940f __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 397
    16  UIKit                               0x026a9754 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 493
    17  UIKit                               0x026a923b -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 182
    18  3                                   0x006afc39 GADCategories_GADSlot_Mediation + 16778
    19  3                                   0x0067c5a9 GADCategories_NSString_GADPathValidation + 31687
    20  3                                   0x006fc09f GADAbsoluteTimeMilliseconds + 3657
    21  3                                   0x0069d1c5 GADCategories_DFPBannerView_CustomRenderedAd + 17414
    22  3                                   0x00111885 -[AppodealAdMobInterstitialAdapter presentFromRootViewController:] + 81
    23  3                                   0x0007f6fa -[AppodealModalAdMediator presentModalAdapterFromViewController:] + 250
    24  3                                   0x0007fcc3 -[AppodealModalAdMediator presentFromRootViewController:] + 368
    25  3                                   0x0007a842 -[AppodealInterstitialAdManager presentWithRootViewController:] + 386
    26  3                                   0x000a0564 -[AppodealSdk presentInterstitialFromRootViewController:] + 94
    27  3                                   0x00062b6d +[Appodeal showAd:rootViewController:] + 133
    28  3                                   0x00031943 _TFC1_18GameViewController16showInterstitialfT_T_ + 131
    29  3                                   0x00037a2a _TFC1_9GameScene12touchesBeganfTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_9withEventGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 5994
    30  3                                   0x00038040 _TToFC1_9GameScene12touchesBeganfTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_9withEventGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 128
    31  SpriteKit                           0x07162866 -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 1093
    32  UIKit                               0x025432af -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 456
    33  UIKit                               0x025445cc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1159
    34  UIKit                               0x024e5be8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
    35  UIKit                               0x024ba769 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7795
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x04ed7e5f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x04ecdaeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x04eccf08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x04ecc846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x04ecc65b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x08708664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    42  GraphicsServices                    0x087084a1 GSEventRun + 104
    43  UIKit                               0x024c0eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    44  3                                   0x0002b811 main + 145
    45  libdyld.dylib                       0x0815aa25 start + 1
)
2016-06-05 19:54:29 +0000 [Appodeal 0.10.6][error][AppodealAdQueue] Error while refreshing ad queue: Error Domain=com.appodeal Code=708610 "Got error message from server: " UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Got error message from server: }
2016-06-05 19:54:40 +0000 [Appodeal 0.10.6][error][AppodealAdQueue] Error while refreshing ad queue: Error Domain=com.appodeal Code=708610 "Got error message from server: " UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Got error message from server: }
2016-06-05 19:55:02 +0000 [Appodeal 0.10.6][error][AppodealAdQueue] Error while refreshing ad queue: Error Domain=com.appodeal Code=708610 "Got error message from server: " UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Got error message from server: }
gameover
speed1.1
speed1.0
2016-06-05 19:55:42 +0000 [Appodeal 0.10.6][error][AppodealAdQueue] Error while refreshing ad queue: Error Domain=com.appodeal Code=708610 "Got error message from server: " UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Got error message from server: }
2016-06-05 19:57:03 +0000 [Appodeal 0.10.6][error][AppodealAdQueue] Error while refreshing ad queue: Error Domain=com.appodeal Code=708610 "Got error message from server: " UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Got error message from server: }